# Get x from Some x in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

So I have a function that returns either None or Some [floats]
I am trying to pass the return value of this function to a function that accepts [floats]

```
match r with
| None -> None
| Some x -> func x
```

But this is telling me x has type 'a option. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this small fragment, it looks like the compiler is telling you that `func x` (not `x`) has type `'a option`. That's because you return `None` in the other branch of the `match`. The type of `None` is indeed `'a option`. I assume your problem is that `func x` doesn't return an option type.

If your function doesn't return an option type, you need to decide what to do when `r` is `None`. I.e., you need to choose some kind of default behavior. You can't return `None` unless you return `Some (func x)` in the other branch.

You can raise an exception, require caller to supply a default, or supply a default yourself.